# How can I get the IP address that a specific process is connected to? (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, networking

More precisely, I need to access these values that are shown on perfmon.exe:

[image]
I've already tried netstat, performance counter, some other classes refering to networking, but I didn't end up with a method to access those values.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try WMI: `ROOT\StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetTCPConnection`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/nettcpipprov/msft-nettcpconnection

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't show the IP address although MSFT_NetUDPEndpoint shows me the correct port the process is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Among other APIs, Perfmon calls [GetExtendedTcpTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable) with **TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS** flag

Comment: Just tried that aswell, altough I can find the TCP remote addresses of the processes, I can't find the process I need because it uses UDP. I tried the GetExtendedUdpTable, and altough the process I need shows on the list, the Local Address is 0.0.0.0 and there is no Remote Address to be found.